# How could I achieve JQuery style method calls on IEnumerables in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

In JQuery you can write `$('.my-class').hide()` and it will call `hide()` on *all* the results. There's no `for` loop, no iterating, no LINQ extensions and lambdas etc. and it makes dealing with lists super fun. I want to be able to have this functionality on IEnumerables in C#. I think Matlab has a similarly concise syntax when operating on arrays/matrices.

Long story short, I want the following code (or similar) to work:

```
class Program
{
    static List<MyClass> MyList = new List<MyClass>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            MyList.Add(new MyClass());

        MyList.MyMethod();
        // should be exactly equivalent to:
        MyList.Select(n => n.MyMethod());
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public int MyMethod() { return 123; }
}
```

I'm aware this is possible on a case-by-case basis using extension methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> MyMethod(this IEnumerable<MyClass> lst)
{
    return lst.Select(n => n.MyMethod());
}
```

But we'd have to create one extension method for **every single method** on **every single type** that you wanted this behaviour on.

Ideally this would be possible for all types and all methods and still be type-safe at compile time. I suspect I'm asking too much from the C# language here, but **how would we do this or something similar in a as-generic-as-possible way?**

## Possible solutions:

1. **Auto-generate extension methods for particular types.** If we only intend to use this notation for a few types, we could just generate the extension methods once automatically. This would achieve the exact syntax and full type safety but generating code would be a pain.
2. **A single extension method that returns a dynamic object built using reflection on the supplied type.** The idea is that we'd use reflection to iterate through the type's methods and build up a dynamic object that would have all the methods like `.MyMethod()` that would behind the scenes call `Select(...)` on the IEnumerable. The syntax would end up being something like `MyList.Selector().MyMethod()`. But now we've lost the syntax and type safety. Clever, maybe. Useful, probably not.
3. **Intercepting method calls?** Is it possible to decide how to react to a method call at runtime? I don't know. Again you'd lose type safety.

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with Intefaces, Generic Methods, and/or Generic Type Constraints?

Comment: @Neolisk Presumably you meant JavaScript, not Java...Also, he's looking for a way of doing this in a type safe manor.  While C# likely doesn't provide the tools for doing this using the syntax the OP is looking for, the OP *isn't* looking to do all of this dynamically.

Comment: In either case, the comment doesn't add anything to the discussion.  It's like asking how to make an apple pie, and then someone saying you should use pears.

Comment: Also your example Method Extension is not like most jQuery fluent methods (*not all*), it returns the method result, not the original list.

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with interfaces, generic methods and type constraints. And as far as I can tell there's no reason that achieving this would *have* to sacrifice type safety. It would only be valid to call one of T's methods on IEnumerable<T>, and it would be perfectly well defined at compile-time what that did.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: It's more like someone asking to [shoot oneself in the foot](http://www.fullduplex.org/humor/2006/10/how-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-in-any-programming-language/), and me trying to convince not to do that. :)

Comment: What you're asking for isn't how jQuery works, by the way. If we were to translate jQuery to C#, we would end up with something like `class jQuery : IEnumerable<HTMLElement>`. All the methods are defined in `jQuery` (aka `$`), not `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution is using dynamic objects. If you are willing to throw away type safety, you can make a IEnumerable type that behaves statically when needed and dynamically otherwise, here's a sample prototype:

```
public class DynamicIEnumerable<T> : DynamicObject, IEnumerable<T>
{
     public IEnumerable<T> _enumerable;
     public DynamicIEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
     {
         this._enumerable = enumerable;
     }

     public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
     {
         result = new DynamicIEnumerable<T>(_enumerable.Select(x => (T)typeof(T).InvokeMember(binder.Name, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, x, null)));
         return true;
     }

     public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
     {
         return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
     }

     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
     {
         return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
     }
  }
```

In `TryInvokeMember`, the invoked member on IENumerable is applied on all items using reflection. The only constraints on this approach is that you have to return `this` in invoked method. Here's a sample of how to use this approach:

```
 public class SomeClass
 { 
    public int Value {get;set;}
    public SomeClass(int value)
    {
        this.Value = x;
    }
    public SomeClass Plus10()
    {
        Value += 10;
        return this;
    }
 }


 static void Main()
 {
     dynamic d = new DynamicIEnumerable<X>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new SomeClass(x)));
     foreach (var res in d.Plus10().Plus10())
         Console.WriteLine(res.Value);
 }
```

Comment: Excellent. This is what I had in mind with `3. Intercepting method calls...` I hadn't heard about overriding TryInvokeMember, which achieves the syntax that I was after.

Comment: Why do you want this functionality though?

Comment: Hacking around with C# for the fun of it. Not going in production code. Although if it could be done with type safety it would have more utility.

Answer (score -1):

> how would we do this or something similar in a as-generic-as-possible way?

This isn't a pretty solution but it does work:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public void MyMethod()
  {
  }
  public void MyMethod2()
  {
  }
}
```

Extension Method:

```
public static class WeirdExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> CallOnAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> instance , 
                                                Action<T> call)
    {
        foreach(var item in instance)
        {
            call(item);
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Usage (chaining/fluent):

```
var blah = new List<MyClass>();

blah.CallOnAll(b => b.MyMethod())
  .CallOnAll(b => b.MyMethod2());
```

*Notes*

This isn't quite possible due to a the underlying assumption that you'd have to `every single method on every single type`.  In jQuery/Html there is only one underlying type of an Html Element.  All elements are exposed to the same methods (whether or not the type supports it).  In jQuery, you can call `$('head').hide()` but it won't do anything visually, but because it is an element, it will be inline styled.  If you need a new method, you do have a build one, but for only *one* type because there is only *one* type.

In contrast with C# **you** build your types (many many types) and they all have different methods (sure there could be overlap).

Comment: He mentioned this specifically in the question, and explained why it wasn't what he wanted.   `But we'd have to create one extension method for every single method on every single type that you wanted this behaviour on.`

Comment: Modified, but ugly and really seems useless.

Comment: The whole premise here is to avoid calling an additional method and using an explicit lambda.  This is avoiding neither.

Comment: I think you're asking to much in both directions.  With jQuery calling `.Hide()` will internally call hide on each element.  My method is doing the same.  He can't have both what he asked for which was `type-safe at compile time` and your assumption of not using an `explicit lambda`.  It's obviously not perfect, but it does as he asks `something similar in a as-generic-as-possible way`.

Comment: Thanks Erik, yes this does achieve the chaining syntax that JQuery allows and isn't written specifically for any one type or method. But @Servy is right, it wasn't the chaining syntax which I was after, it was more getting rid of lambda statements for a more concise syntax.

Comment: You only options are, using lambda, or writing a method for each type for each method.

Comment: Does the supporting extension method add anything that calling `blah.ToList().Foreach(x => x.MyMethod())` doesn't?

Comment: [void ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) return void so it can't be chained.  I also avoid Lambda foreach (like the plague) as [Eric Lippert explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).  But doesn't prevent me from helping other use  lambda's for side affects.

Comment: @ErikPhilips You say you avoid a `ForEach` method like the plague, and yet you just wrote a version of it here.  You called it something different, but that's about it.  Your method has all of the same problems as `ForEach` that Eric describes.

Comment: @Michael It doesn't pull the entire result set into memory at once; it allows them to be streamed.  It doesn't create a list and waste all of the time it takes to populate it (involving the creating of some number of backing arrays being constantly allocated, populated, and then discarded).  And that's in addition to Erik's small semantic change that he described.

Comment: @Servy OK. While the answer allows the results to be streamed, it blocks until complete - wouldn't `yield return item;` be prudent?

Comment: @Michael It depends on the semantics desired.  If you want to defer execution, then that's what you'd need to do.  It also depends on whether or not you want to return the original `IEnumerable` and iterate it multiple times or not.  Personally I wouldn't find *either* method something that should be used.

Comment: @Servy did you read my comment *But doesn't prevent me from helping other use lambda's for side affects.*?  I certainly wouldn't use it but I don't let my religious views on good/bad prevent me from at least attempting a solution for someone else.